# grep -E {,1} showing results that have more than 1 occurrence

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I've been trying to figure out how to grep a line with only N occurrences of a character.

```
[root@example DIR]# grep -E "6{,1}" test.txt
6543
6625
6668
6868
6666
1161
```

What I want is for grep to print out the following:

```
[root@example DIR]# grep -E "6{,1}" test.txt
6543
1161
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can we assume that all characters are decimal digits?

Comment: Basically your problem is lack of anchoring. Describe the whole line and it will work.

Comment: `6666` has a single occurrence of `6` in no less than four different places, so obviously it's included!

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, all decimal digits

Comment: As an aside, don't be `root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "what am I missing" part is: Regular expressions will ignore trailing context once a match is found unless you tell them not to.  So `666` matches `6{,1}` because the first `6` matches and you have not said you don't want to allow additional `6` instances after that occurrence.

You could use a more-complex regex like `^([^6]*6){,1}[^6]*$` but I would actually tackle this with Awk:

```
awk -F 6 'NF==2' file
```

will find all lines in `file` which have exactly one occurrence of `6`.

We cleverly use `6` as the field delimiter and examine the number of fields when Awk has read a line and split it into fields.  The variable `NF` conveniently tells us the number of resulting fields.

Awk programs have the form `condition { action }` where both parts are optional. With no condition, the `{ action }` is taken on every input line.  With no `{ action }`, the default action is to print lines which meet the condition. Here, the condition is `NF==2`.

Answer (score 3):

With awk I'd:

```
$ awk '/6/&&!/6.*6/' file
6543
1161
```

It translates to `grep` like:

```
$ grep 6 file | grep -v 6.*6
6543
1161
```

**Edit:**

@Sundeep's clever idea to use 6 as a field separator and to count the fields (see comments):

```
$ awk -F6 'NF==2' file
6543
1161
```

^ his comment below.

Comment: come on, you are not suggesting the simplest way of using number of fields with `6` as field separator? ;)

Comment: Doh, didn't think of that. Post it. :D

Comment: nah, it's cool, you can add it... there's a duplicate somewhere, too lazy to search ;)

Comment: Thanks @JamesBrown so awk to the rescue :)

Comment: @Allan just a case of remembering this technique from some other answer here or in unix.stackexchange...

Answer (score 2):

You need left and right bounds, else following matches can be ignored.

```
grep -E "^[^6]*6[^6]*$" *
```

This means:

- ^ Start of line
- [^6]* Non sixes, as much as you like
- 6 one six
- followed by non sixes, arbitrary amount
- $ end of line.

  grep -E "6{,1}" *

means just zero to one one 6, at some position in the pattern.

Comment: Thank you. So how would you go about finding 2 occurrence of 6s?

Comment: one more block of non-6 followed by a six. `egrep "^[^8]*8[^8]*8[^8]*$"` (My test data already contained 2 eights, but not sixes). Okay, the next question is, what to do about 791 6es, or 14 to 22 of them. :) Then I would use sed, delete every non-six, and use a 6{14,22} expression, yielding the line number and looking up those line numbers in the original file.

Comment: Oh, now you can use grouping and curly braces: `egrep "^[^8]*(8[^8]*){2}$" * `

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `grep` then you can do it simply by activating the perl regex mode `-P` and using positive lookbehind and by taking every lines except the ones that matches using `-v`

```
grep -Pv "(?<=6)[^6]*6" input                                                                                                                
6543
1161
```

If you do not have GNU `grep` then you will have to use a pipe and make it in 2 steps.

```
grep 6 input | grep -vE '6.*6'                                                                                                               
6543
1161
```